# Add all numbers from 1 through n and print their sum

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to write a program to add all the numbers starting from 1 through n and print their sum. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code. I am getting 1 as an output.

```
def problem1_3(num):
    sum_= 0
    num = int(num)
    for i in range(1,num):
        sum_ = sum_ + i
        print(sum_)
        i+=1
        return(sum_)
```

Comment: you are `return`ing too early. de-intent the `return` statement and allow the `for` loop to finish

Comment: The indentation of your return statement makes it exit the function within the loop (at the first pass).  Also, your range will exclude the last value, you need `range(1,num+1)` and incrementing `i` is not necessary because the for loop already does that for you as it runs through the range.

Comment: It's a better idea to write a function that only calculates the sum, and then print the result of calling that function. That is, separate computation from presentation.

Comment: Delete `i+=1`, you do not need that.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the sum_ on the first iteration of the function. You want to finish the for loop, and only then return it. Read more about [loops in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), they are based on indentation, unlike some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes that you are making in your code:

1- You are incrementing `i` by `+1` but you don't have to do this because python will automatically increment loop variable.

2- You are returning your `sum_` variable inside for loop that's why you got `1` as an output.

```
def problem1_3(num):
    sum_= 0
    num = int(num)
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        sum_ = sum_ + i
        #print(sum_)
        # i+=1
    return(sum_)

ans = problem1_3(5)
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are returning inside your for loop, so it does not go to completion.

but if you would like an easier more concise way to write that function,

```
def problem1_3(num):
    return sum(range(num)) #for up to, but not including num
```

or

```
def problem1_3(num):
    return sum(range(num+1)) #for up to, AND including num
```

Since you already have the range function, range produces a list of numbers. So range(5) is [0,1,2,3,4]
and summing them will get you 1+2+3+4

it's just a shorter way of doing the same thing.